# How to show content of selected item in QTable in a box?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to show this information by slots but I know very basic and not able to do that. Appreciate if anyone can help.

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what you want. What do you mean by QTable and box?

Comment: Show what information? What "slots"? What "box"?

Comment: When user click on an item in tableview the selected Item will printout in the QLineEdit

Comment: Get the contents of the table view and insert it in the QLineEdit? Do not see a big problem there, this has to be done in your source code of course. Get the Objects by name and manipulate them in the generated slot from the layout editor.

Comment: Are you seeking the signal fired as the item in table is selected?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect the signal currentChanged of the selection model for tableview to some slot and set the text of line edit to the text of the selected item:

```
QObject::connect(ui->tableView->selectionModel(),SIGNAL(currentChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)),this,SLOT(printItem(QModelIndex)));

void myClass::printItem(QModelIndex current)
{
    QModelIndex index=ui->tableView->model()->index(current.row(),current.column());
    QString text=index.data().toString();
    ui->lineEdit->setText(text);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not really clear. You should explain the content of your picture in text.

If you have the items of your table view ("Registered servers" ?) in an item model, you can use a [QDataWidgetMapper](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdatawidgetmapper.html) in the widget you want to use to display the details of one item. You set the QDataWidgetMapper with your model used in the table view, and associate widgets (like your QLineEdit) to columns in your model with `addMapping()`